# How to make the window borderless in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, opencv, borderless

I want to create a program similar to Monik.ai or Ukagaka, but I am very new to this... and I need to make the window borderless but I can't figure out how.
Here is my code; How do I make the window borderless?

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk

image = cv2.imread('Sprites/ph1.png' ,-1)
print(image)

cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Or is there a better way to do this? (Also, how would I make the window always be on top?)

Comment: Read [Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method)

Comment: What os are you on?